# In bootstrap .pull-right for align right .pull-left for align left then What for center?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap .pull-right for align right .pull-left for align left then What for center ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap's `.pull-left` and `.pull-right`, work using css-float.

The way float works is by flowing following inline elements around the floated element.

css-float support: `left`, `right`, `none`. There is no center option. Therefore, there is no `.pull-center`.

You can align all inline elements within a block element by applying the css: `text-align: center` to the parent.

If the element is you're trying to center should be inline AND block-like, you should set it to have `display: inline-block`.

You can see some text-alignment options in bootstrap here:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment
Note that the `<p>` is a block-type element, and the text within has an implicit text-node which is `display: inline`.

The `center-block` class can only be used on images:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Answer (score 3):

`center-block` for centering an element in Bootstrap.

You can test by an image:

```
<img class="center-block" src="xxx.PNG"/ >
```

Comment: this not working in the case of div

Comment: I have mentioned element...........

Answer (score 3):

try `center-block` or use grid columns to center your element. If text use `text-center`